# api gateway to run cloudformation commands

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to use API gateway as a proxy for cloud formation API, so I can just send post commands like create/update stack with a JSON request body and it will pass through to cloud formation without needing a lambda in the middle.

Comment: Yes it’s possible. Is there another question underlying? Like how it is done?

Comment: Yes please if you have an example of the json payload i can send the post request to CF as integration endpoint

Comment: I have created an api gateway backed with cloudformation as aws service with passthrough, but i don't know how to submit the post request to do a stack update or any other operation.